# Problemas ao fazer chamada usando Retrofit no Android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, volley

Sou estudante e estou com dificuldade de entender onde estou errando num trabalho que o professor passou. Descrevendo brevemente, o professor disponibilizou uma API no GitHub, o qual após realizar a instalação podemos adicionar produtos, fornecedores e clientes (usando o app PostMan). Segue o link da API - https://github.com/newba/api-d73-a2017. Ela usa o endereço http://localhost:3033.
Enfim, o trabalho é fazer um CRUD usando à nossa escolha a biblioteca VOLLEY ou a biblioteca RETROFIT. No Volley nao consegui fazer nada. No Retrofit consigo acessar o metodo find da API, mas nao consigo mostrar a lista na minha Activity.

Código da classe ProdutoLista

```
    public class ProdutosLista extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.produtos_lista);


}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    final ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProdutos);

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiInterface.retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    /*
    ==============================================================================
    Charging... para evitar açoes indesejadas na aplicação
    ==============================================================================
     */

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ProdutosLista.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    final Call<List<Produto>> call = apiInterface.getProdutos();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Produto>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Produto>> call, Response<List<Produto>> response) {

            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            final List<Produto> listaProdutos = response.body();
            if (listaProdutos != null){
                ProdutosAdapter adapter = new ProdutosAdapter(getBaseContext(), listaProdutos);

                lista.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Produto>> call, Throwable t) {

            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problema de acesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Este é o codigo da Interface:

```
    public interface ApiInterface {

@GET ("/products")
Call<List<Produto>>getProdutos();

public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3033")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

}

Esta é a classe modelo de Produto

```
    public class Produto {

String code;
String name;
int price;
String description;
int inventoryActual;
String supplier;

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getInventoryActual() {
    return inventoryActual;
}

public void setInventoryActual(int inventoryActual) {
    this.inventoryActual = inventoryActual;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getSupplier() {
    return supplier;
}

public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
}
```

}

Esta é a classe Adapter

```
    public class ProdutosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Produto>{

private final Context context;
private final List<Produto> elementos;

public ProdutosAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> elementos) {
    super(context, R.layout.linha, elementos);
    this.context = context;
    this.elementos = elementos;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha, parent, false);

        TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView code = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        TextView price = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        TextView description = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView inventoryActual = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.inventoryActual);
        TextView supplier = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.supplier);

        /*
        ==================================================================================
        Set values
        ==================================================================================
         */

        name.setText(elementos.get(position).getName());
        code.setText(elementos.get(position).getCode());
        price.setText(Integer.toString(elementos.get(position).getPrice()));
        description.setText(elementos.get(position).getDescription());
        inventoryActual.setText(Integer.toString(elementos.get(position).getInventoryActual()));
        supplier.setText(elementos.get(position).getSupplier());

        return  rowView;

    }
```

}

E finalmente esse é XML do layout personalizado da lista

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/supplier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventoryActual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="$" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Aqui a imagem do erro e o log da linha de comando mostrando que ele acessou o método da API]

Aqui o Json:

```
    {
"total": 2,
"limit": 10,
"skip": 0,
"data": [
    {
        "code": "002",
        "name": "Rims",
        "price": 45,
        "description": "R15 Corolla",
        "inventoryActual": 12,
        "supplier": "NCdaojXnykwxBV2n",
        "removed": null,
        "onlineStatus": null,
        "notes": null,
        "categId": null,
        "_id": "3qsvzvtpDc2JmAEM"
    },
    {
        "code": "001",
        "name": "Pneu",
        "price": 30,
        "description": "R15 Corolla",
        "inventoryActual": 10,
        "supplier": "qvql3wCvEInl5RDZ",
        "removed": null,
        "onlineStatus": null,
        "notes": null,
        "categId": null,
        "_id": "D9ete272UCGgjKDQ"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Pelo jeito a requisição está caindo no bloco `onFailure`, o que normalmente indica um erro na rede ou algum erro ao criar a requisição ou resposta. Qual é a stack do `Throwable t`?

Comment: @Leonardo Lima, de acordo com a documentaçao:  Throwable initCause(Throwable cause). Initializes the cause of this throwable to the specified value. A throwable contains a snapshot of the execution stack of its thread at the time it was created.

Comment: Ele perguntou qual a mensagem que está dando no `Throwable t`

Comment: Sorry, rsrs. Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Entao o problema é que sua chama espera uma `Lista` de produtos, mas o JSON está respondendo com o `Objeto`. Se tu postar o JSON que está recebendo posso lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: @LMaker postado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Gson não está conseguindo converter a resposta para o tipo informado. De acordo com seu JSON, você deverá criar uma classe que envolve a lista de produtos:

```
public class RespostaProduto {

  private int total;
  private int limit;
  private int skip;
  private List<Produto> data;

  // Getters e setters
}
```

E alterar a sua interface:

```
@GET ("/products")
Call<RespostaProduto>getProdutos();
```

Comment: Estao dando outros erros neste momento. Estou tentando entende-los neste momento. A resposta foi importante para entender o que se passa

Comment: Error:(58, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable List
Error:(58, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable Produto
(Na classe ProdutosLista)..  fiz todas as alteracoes q foram pedidas depois que fiz a modificação sugerida. Fiz um cast tbem mas ele da um crash na aplicacao qdo tento essa gambiarra

Comment: Lembrou de importar as respectivas classes? `List` e `Produto`?

Comment: Sim. No log ele diz que está retornando uma lista vazia. List = null